# What is the modern conception of the syntactic structure of a possessive?

Tags: syntax, reference-request, minimalism, genitive

I'm trying to find modern work (more modern than Abney 1987) on the structure of a genitive phrase. Abney has a possessive phrase, like my dog, headed by a D head which assigns genitive case to "my," which is in Spec,DP position. "dog" is an NP, a complement of D.

What have been some modern updates to this structure?

Comment: What language do you aim at? English? Different language? Or a cross-linguistic comparison? I suspect this will highly differ among languages. Also are you interested particularly in phrases like "my dog" or other possessive variations as well ("I have a dog", "dog-I" / dog-1SG, ezafet constructions,...)?

Comment: If you want answers strictly from Minimalism then please say so in the question itself - using a tag is not enough to clearly communicate what you want.

Comment: "My dog" is an NP in which the NP "dog" is head (not complement), and the NP "my" is the genitive dependent. Thus it's an NP functioning within the structure of another. (Huddleston & Pullum, The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language, 2002)

Comment: There is probably a book or monograph that can answer this question.

Comment: There is a hypothesis (knocking around since 1987) that noun phrases like "my dog" are DPs, and the head is the D.  However, CGEL has a couple of clear arguments against this; you can see them on pages 357-358.